# MySQL Delete Statement of a Table

Tags: mysql, delete-row

I'm trying to create a MySQL Delete statement of this table.

The Delete statement should delete the whole rows data. But it's not working.

Details can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdmi0.png)

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No sample data ,no code segment, no definition of not working, table definition as image (which some folk won't be able to see) You could do more to help yourself.

Comment: Details should be here. Not there.

Answer (score 0):

please try following statement in mysql console.

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
DELETE FROM books where ...;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: I am creating a java cancel booking code. So the statement should be in  the main code.